# C++ Simple Window Creation is executing java code for some reason?

Tags: c++

I'm following the walkthrough of how to create a simple c++ application window [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-170), and as far as I can tell my code is exactly the same as on the website. However whenever I try to execute the code it throws up this [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC53O.png) where it seems to execute some java code and infinitely try to connect to a server. The problem is I have no earthly idea why this could be happening or what could be causing it. On cursory google searches it seems like it might be related to tesseract or some other package but I don't know why some outside package would ever be doing something in my code when I haven't included it. My project is a standard console app from Visual Studio but with my code replacing the default. I imagine this has nothing to do with the actual code but I have included it just in case.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour Application");
HINSTANCE hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(_In_ HWND   hWnd,_In_ UINT   message,_In_ WPARAM wParam,_In_ LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, Windows desktop!");


    switch (message){
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Here your application is laid out.
        // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!"
        // in the top left corner.
        TextOut(hdc,
            5, 5,
            greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        // End application specific layout section.

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,_T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),_T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: How are you running the resultant executable? Via the IDE/editor? "By hand" from a command-line? Double-clicking on the produced file?

Comment: I'm running through Visual Studio's Start without Debugging.

Comment: Hmm. This kinda sounds like a Visual Studio thing, configuration or corruption or something. What happens if you run _with_ debugging, perhaps setting a breakpoint on the first line in `WinMain`? You say this is a "standard console app". Windows desktop applications are not console apps, so make sure your project is configured correctly

Comment: I created a new project using Visual Studio's Empty project template and copy pasted the code from the tutorial to make sure it was consistent across projects, and I have created other small projects through VS that seemed to work fine. When trying to use Visual Studio's step into command to debug the first thing that happens is the console opening same as above but there's no pointer in the file to designate what line caused it to happen. I'm truly at a loss what could be causing it.

Comment: Visual Studio has a template specifically for creating Windows desktop applications. Among other things it configures things to use `WinMain` as the app's entry point. Have you tried using that?

Comment: Unfortunately I had some debug settings setup that didn't allow me to see the actual start point of my code originally, now I at least know that the first thing being compiled in my code is the main function of a file called svpaint.cpp, that then tries to connect to a server and completely supersedes my written code. I'm unsure why this file would be built with my project though, given I created an empty project with no files other than the one with my code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was from a library by the name of Tesseract, I'm unsure why it was compiling with the code at all, but I can be sure that it was causing this, and a quick uninstall of the library fixed everything.